# find command can't find zcompile

Tags: zsh

Since I'm new-ish to zsh my entire concept could be wrong for all I know but I've noticed that my system can't find `zcompile` when I run it from a `find` command like so:

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.zwc" -exec zcompile {} \;
```

The error I get is:

> ```
> find: zcompile: No such file or directory
> ```

but I can run `zcompile` from the prompt and get a `.zwc` no problem.  Does anybody have any idea why batching with `find` isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zcompile` is a `zsh` shell builtin only available from within the shell, `find` is a separate command from the shell so that can't work.

`zsh` globs can easily replace `find` here:

```
set -o extendedglob # for ^, best in ~/.zshrc
for file (./**/^*.zwc(N.)) zcompile $file
```

(here omitting hidden files and files in hidden dirs which is probably preferable; if not add the `D` glob qualifier).

If you wanted to use `find`, you'd need to have `find` output the list and the shell retrieve that list to pass it to its `zcompile` builtin. Something like:

```
find . ! -name "*.zwc" -type f -print0 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    zcompile $file
  done
```

Or you'd need `find` to start a `zsh` shell to run its `zcompile` on the found files:

```
find . ! -name "*.zwc" -type f -exec zsh -c '
  for file do
    zcompile $file
  done' zsh {} +
```

(note that some `find` implementations (including GNU `find`) have a limitation that `zsh` globs don't have in that their `*` won't match sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale).